# Dictionary<string, string> Object and sorting in asp.net 2.0 or alternative

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-2.0

How do you sort a dictionary object in C# 2.0 for asp.net or is their an alternative to Dictionay for sorting this is to sort a countries list alphabetically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the [`SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) class, which will automatically sort itself by the key.

If you want to sort the values, you can use a `List<string>`:

```
List<string> values = new List<string>(dict.Values);
values.Sort();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try a SortedList in System.Collections.  There's also a generic version (System.Collections.Generic.SortedList).

Here's MSDN's [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx).